# Redshift COPY CSV NULL AS '\0' does not work if a field starts with '\0'

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test_null_as_tab"
(
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL  ENCODE lzo
    ,"email" VARCHAR(128)   ENCODE lzo
    ,"domain" VARCHAR(128)   ENCODE lzo
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN;
```

data_file1: email fields starts with a NUL char

```
91291240    [NUL CHAR \0]sfassssad@asdas.me asdas.me
91291240    [NUL CHAR \0]sfassssad@asdas.me asdas.me
```

data_file2: email field does not start with a NUL char

```
91291240    -[NUL CHAR \0]sfassssad@asdas.me    asdas.me
91291240    -[NUL CHAR \0]sfassssad@asdas.me    asdas.me
```

Following COPY command fails with `.sfassssad@asdas.me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1218    Invalid null byte - field longer than 1 byte` in `stl_load_errors`

```
copy test_null_as_tab
from 's3://abrar/data_file1'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id;aws_secret_access_key='
CSV DELIMITER '\t' QUOTE '\036' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF TRUNCATECOLUMNS NULL AS '\000';
```

Following COPY command successfully loads data into table

```
copy test_null_as_tab
from 's3://abrar/data_file2'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
CSV DELIMITER '\t' QUOTE '\036' COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF TRUNCATECOLUMNS NULL AS '\000';
```

I was unsuccessful in loading data_file1 with any of the COPY command options.

How can I get the Redshift COPY command to load data that has NUL char at the beginning of a field?

Comment: your question should be "how do i work around this?" as we cannot answer why a redshift feature works like it does.  Can you read the data as it is or does it fail whatever options you use?

Comment: Given that i cannot change the upstream data, i have tried all possible options in Redshift COPY command but i was unable to get this to load the data. There are no workaround that i can think off

Comment: Is this related? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-escape (The control character 0x00 (NUL) cannot be escaped and should be removed from the input data or converted. This character is treated as an end of record (EOR) marker, causing the remainder of the record to be truncated.)

Comment: http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html -> NULL AS (this section talks about converting NUL char(EOR char) in the input data to NULL char). Its true that we cannot escape NUL char but we still can replace it with NULL char.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this somehow? I experience the same problem.